# No Adjacency Combinatorics Problem via Generating Function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, generating-functions

I would like to find the generating function solution for the following combinatorics/probability problem. I have a combinatorial solution and the generating function deduced thereof. But I can not fathom the direct interpretation of it. I would like to reverse the current solving process and directly deduce the following or some other generating function, then get the relevant coefficient as the solution.

In a stack of $W$ white cards, $G$ green cards and $R$ red cards, what is the number of arrangement for no green card is next to a red card?

One solution is to view the $W$ white cards as dividers and leaving $W+1$ slots in between them together with both ends. For each $r\in \{1,2,\dots,R\}$ and $g\in\{1,2,\dots, G\}$, designate non-overlappingly $r$ slots for inserting the red cards and $g$ slots for the green cards. There are ${W+1\choose r,g}$ combinations. For each of these combinations, we insert $R$ red cards into the previously designated $r$ red slots, and there are ${R-1\choose r-1}$ ways of insertion. Do the same for the $g$ green cards and there are ${G-1\choose g-1}$ ways of insertion. Multiplying them and summing over $r$ and $g$, we arrive at the desired total number of arrangements:

$$\sum_{r=1}^R\sum_{g=1}^G{W+1\choose r,g}{R-1\choose R-r}{G-1\choose G-g}.$$

But this is the coefficient of $x^Ry^G$ in $(1+x+y)^{W+1}(1+x)^{R-1}(1+y)^{G-1}$.

Now how do I deduce this generating function directly from the problem?

Comment: I am trying to follow your count. When you say there are (W + 1; r,g) combinations (or ways to designate non-overlappingly r slots for red and g slots for green), does  this  mean (W + 1,r)*(W + 1 - r,g)

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer: Yes, you can easily verify that. The first symbol is the multinomial coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

We consider the set $ \mathcal{V}^{\star}$ of words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{g,r,w\}$$ and the set $B=\{gr,rg\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of wanted words of length $n$.

To ease reading we derive at first a generating function $f(s)$ which provides the number of valid words of length $n$ and then we do a refinement and derive a function $f(s;z_g,z_r,z_w)$ which also keeps track of the characters.

> **Introduction**
>
> According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=3$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* with
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])&=-s^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])s\tag{3}\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])&=-s^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])s\\
> \end{align*}
>   and get
>
> \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])=-\frac{s^2}{1+s}
> \end{align*}
>
> It follows
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-3s+2\frac{s^2}{1+s}}\\
> &=\frac{1+s}{1-2s-s^2}\\
> &=1+3s+7s^2+17s^3+41s^4+99s^5\\
> &\qquad+239s^6+577s^7+1393s^8+3363s^9+\cdots
> \end{align*}

We observe e.g. the coefficient  of $s^3$ is $17$ giving   the    number of all valid     words of length $3$. This is in accordance with the number $3^3=27$ of all words of length $3$  and the   $10$ invalid words
\begin{align*}
\{ggr,grg,rgg,grr,rgr,rrg,grw,rgw,wgr,wrg\}
\end{align*}

> **Keeping track of characters**
>
> We refine the technique above by keeping track of the characters $g,r$ and $w$. We encode the characters with $z_g,z_r$ and $z_w$ and start with a recalculation of the weights.
>
> We obtain        according to (3)
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])&=-z_gz_rs^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])z_rs\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])&=-z_gz_rs^2-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])z_gs\\
> \end{align*}
>   and   get 
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])&=-\frac{z_gz_r(1-z_rs)s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}\\
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])&=-\frac{z_gz_r(1-z_gs)s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}
> \end{align*}
>
> It follows according to (2)
>
> \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})&=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[gr])+\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[rg])\\
> &=-\frac{z_gz_r(1-z_rs)s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}-\frac{z_gz_r(1-z_gs)s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}\\
> &=-\frac{z_gz_r(1-(z_g+z_rs))s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> We  finally obtain from (1)
>   \begin{align*}
> f(s;&z_g,z_r,z_w)\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-(z_g+z_r+z_w)s+\frac{z_gz_r(1-(z_g+z_rs))s^2}{1-z_gz_rs}}\\
> &=\frac{1-z_gz_rs^2}{1-(z_g+z_r+z_w)s+z_gz_rs^2+z_gz_rz_ws^3}\tag{4}\\
> \\
> &=1+(z_g+z_r+z_w)s+(z_g^2+z_r^2+z_w^2+2z_gw+2z_rw)s^2\\
> &\qquad+(z_g^3+z_r^3+z_w^3+3z_g^2z_w+3z_gz_w^2+3z_r^2z_w+3z_rz_w^2+2z_gz_rz_w)s^3\\
> &\qquad+(z_g^4+z_r^4+z_w^4+2z_g^2z_rz_w+6z_gz_rz_w^2+2z_gz_r^2z_w\\
> &\qquad\qquad+4z_g^3z_w+6z_g^2z_w^2+4z_gz_w^3+4z_r^3z_w+6z_r^2z_w^2+4z_rz_w^3)s^4+\cdots\tag{5}
> \end{align*}

The expansion up  to $s^4$ was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha. When checking e.g. the coefficient of $s^3$ we see the $17$ valid words in detail. The correspondence is
\begin{align*}
z_g^3&\qquad ggg\\
z_r^3&\qquad rrr\\
z_w^3&\qquad www\\
3z_g^2z_w&\qquad ggw,gwg,wgg\\
3z_gz_w^2&\qquad gww,wgw,wwg\\
3z_r^2z_w&\qquad rrw,rwr,wrr\\
3z_rz_w^2&\qquad rww,wrw,wwr\\
2z_gz_rz_w&\qquad gwr,rwg
\end{align*}

*Note:*

- The refined technique of keeping track of letters is presented e.g. in *[Generalisations of the Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.5113.pdf)* by E.J. Kupin and D.S. Yuster.
- The generating function $f(s;z_g,z_r,z_w)$ in the representation (4) corresponds with the result $G(x)$ of @gar.

Comment: Wow, super! Thank you very much for the answer and the references. I do not have time now, but will come back to go through the answer and the papers carefully.

Comment: @Hans: You're welcome! Enjoy! :-)

Answer (score 2):

(The notations are slightly changed here)

We may use a directed graph for such pattern avoiding problems.

Write the matrix as

\begin{align*}
A = \left(\begin{array}{r|rrr}
  & W & G & R \\
\hline
W & w & g & r \\
G & w & g & 0 \\
R & w & 0 & r \\
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

$W,G,R$ are the states to indicate the three colors and $w,g,r$ are the formal variables to indicate the colors.

To obtain the recurrence formula, find the characteristic polynomial,

$$x^{3} - \left(g + r + w\right) x^{2} + g r x + g r w = 0$$

If we indicate $F(a,b,c)$ as the number of ways to arrange the cards, where a,b,c are the number of white, green and red cards respectively, then
$$F(a,b,c) = F(a-1,b,c)+F(a,b-1,c)+F(a,b,c-1)-F(a,b-1,c-1)-F(a-1,b-1,c-1)$$
and set the necessary boundary conditions

To obtain the generating function, find
$$\left(I-x\, A\right)^{-1}$$ 
Each entry will have a g.f. for that entry, and we require the sum of the first row, which is

$$G(x) =\frac{1-g\, r\, x^{2}}{1\, -\, {\left(g\, +\, r\, +\, w\right)+\, g\, r\, x^{2}+g\, r\, w\, x^{3}}}$$

If there are $n=a+b+c$ cards in total, find $[x^n]$ and find the required $[w^a\, g^b\, r^c]$

Richard Stanley's "Enumerative combinatorics" discusses such methods (transfer matrices)

Comment: This graphical and matrix method looks very intriguing. However, the description has left me puzzled. I understand your recursion equation. However, it is not clear how that figures in the derivation of the generating function. Or are you presenting it as a second method of deriving the generating function or simply a recursion solution? Are you multiplying the recursion by $x^wy^rz^g$ and summing over $(w,r,g)$ to obtain the generating function? But if so, this does not seem to gel with the matrix $A$ and the expansion of $(I-xA)^{-1}$.

Comment: This recursion seems not to figure in the graphical or matrix method. Would you be so kind as to write out the details of the derivation? Thank you very much (for the reference as well).

Comment: The notation in the recurrence is inconsistent, let me modify it. I took w,g and r as formal variables in the matrix. The W indicates that the current card is white, and the next card can be any color. But if it is G or R, the next card can't be R or G, so, the corresponding entries are 0.

Comment: The modified notation in recursion equation is better. However, you did not understand my question. I have stated that "I understand your recursion equation". My question is that I do not see the connection between this recursion and the rest of your formulation in graphs and the resolvent of $A$, i.e., $(I-xA)^{-1}$. Could you please write out the derivation of the graphical and matrix representation and the subsequent generating function in details?

Comment: I derived only the matrix. Both the recurrence and the g.f are then obtained from that matrix, for which I used a CAS. What the matrix means is -- if the current card is W and the next card drawn is G, that is allowed, so write 'g'. If the current card is G and the next card drawn is R, it's not allowed, so write 0. Use reasoning along that lines and fill the remaining entries. $I$ is the identity matrix there. I don't have a proof on why that works, but I have found it to be very useful for problems involving patterns.

Comment: Your method looks very intriguing. It looks very much correct. However, I can not trace it out in rigorous steps. I did not find the exact derivation, with the variable weighted adjacency matrix, though I did see the materials on the numerically weighted adjacency matrix, in the chapter on transfer matrix in Richard Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics. Maybe I am not looking in the right place. Would you be so kind as to provide some references on the derivation of your fascinating method?

Comment: I too did not find it exactly as I wrote here. I thought that it might work if I used variables instead of weights, and it did! But I can't prove it formally, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer to the question but some of this information may help.  Lets call a permutation of n (white green or red) cards where no red card is adjacent to a green card a valid arrangement.  The bivariate generating function (b.g.f.) for the number of length n valid arrangements that have exactly k white cards is : c(x,y) = $-((1 + x)/(-1 + x + x y + x^2 y))$.  The coefficient of y^k*x^n is the number of valid arrangements having a total of n cards where exactly k of the cards are white.  c(x,y) does not tell us anything about the number of red and greeen cards in the arrangements (other than that the number of red or green cards is n - k).

I solved this system of equations: a(x, y) == y x a(x, y) + y x b(x, y)
and b(x, y) == 1 + x + x b(x, y) + 2 x a(x, y). I derived these equations directly (i.e. via the symbolic method) from the properties of such arrangements.  a(x,y) is the b.g.f. for valid words that start with a white card.  b(x,y) counts the valid words that are empty or start with a red card or start with a green card.The generating function c(x,y) = a(x,y) + b(x,y).

The first few rows of the triangle are:

1;

2, 1;

2, 4,  1;

2, 8,  6,  1;

2, 12, 18, 8,  1;

2, 16, 38, 32, 10, 1;

2, 20, 66, 88, 50, 12, 1;

> This is Sloane's OEIS A113413.

Also interesting is if you let W = R = G then you get the sequence that starts:
2, 12, 92, 780, 7002, 65226, 623576, 6077196,...  which is A103882

Comment: I think I know what you are attempting to do with the system of generating equations. However, your writing makes your answer enigmatic. In the first paragraph, how does the coefficient relate to the combination sought? I suppose the second paragraph is a Mathematica code. It would be better to write the mathematics in LaTeX format that everyone on this site understands. It is confusing to use some specific computer scripting language without even noting what it is. You can always put your code in a block after clearly stating what it is.

Comment: Could you please write out your logic derivation clearly so that people can verify it?

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I edited the answer to make it a bit better.  I agree that is not a good  answer to your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Are you answering my question or some other question? If it is the latter case, could you please specify what question you are trying to solve? Could you please denote carefully what you mean by "for the number of length n valid arrangements that have exactly k white cards"? Do you mean the total number of cards is $n$ with $k$ white cards within? Are you not going to specify the number of red and green cards? What do you mean by valid? How are there quantities related to the coefficients of your bivariate generating function? Same questions for $a(x,y)$ and $b(x,y)$.

Comment: I made another edit.  Do you mean the total number of cards is n with k white cards within?   Yes.   Are you not going to specify the number of red and green cards?  No, this bivariate generating function only "marks" the number of white cards.  What do you mean by valid?  A permutation of red, green or white cards where no red card is adjacent to a green card.  How are these quantities related to the coefficients of your bivariate generating function? The coefficient of y^k*x^n is the number of valid arrangements having a total of n cards with exactly k white cards.

Comment: You say your answer does not answer my question. Could you please state exactly what question you are answering? "The coefficient of y^k*x^n is the number of valid arrangements" is wrong. By your definition of valid arrangement, it is a function of the number of red and green card. Yet you acknowledge "c(x,y) does not tell us anything about the number of red and green cards in the arrangements (other than that the number of red or green cards is n - k). " So obviously you are concluding the number of valid arrangement does NOT depend on the numbers of the red and green cards, without a proof.

Comment: That is not only an invalid derivation, but the conclusion is obviously wrong.